# Does Imposm3 support windows?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, java, imposm

I want to make a tool in java that can configure import data from OpenStreetMap to PostGIS using Imposm3.

Can I do this in windows?

Comment: What is your end goal?  Routing, Mapping, etc?  Imposm3 is only available for Linux but you might try osm2po.de which is in Java and can run under windows.

Comment: my goals is to changing "mapping.json" in imposm3 based on my user requirement , so the tools should import .pbf file select the key element and send the selected data to the postgis.

Answer (score 1):

You may look this fork:
https://github.com/gaspardle/imposm3
Rather outdated, but working for me on Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 1):

I made an `imposm` repository to create binaries for windows x64.
Here you can check it: [imposm3-for-windows](https://github.com/mghadiri/imposm3-for-windows)

And here is the binaries I made: [0.10.0-windows](https://github.com/mghadiri/imposm3-for-windows/releases/tag/v0.10.0-windows)